# Angularjs Client-Side Routing with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I use `ui-router` (states) for my routing:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/Home',
        templateUrl: '/Home/Home',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/Posts',
        templateUrl: '/Home/Posts',
        controller: 'PostCtrl'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In *html* I have something like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <!--render scripts -->
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews" ngcloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="posts">Posts</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use my menu links (Home, Posts) the app works fine and updates my view in `<ui-view></ui-view>` as needed. When I use the address bar after the first download  to change the url to `localhost:port/Posts`, the app refreshes the page.

Keep in mind that I removed # from links.

Why does angular not know about my routes?

Or how can I set client-side menu with angular?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I tried, menu works well in both varients.
My issue about navigation from address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Knows about your route but you webserver may thinks he need to show the `index.html` page in the map `posts`

Try to set your html5Mode to false and see if it still happens
the [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and look at the part about `Hashbang and HTML5 modes`

and especially the last row `requires server-side configuration: Yes`

Comment: And try to use routes with '#'?

Comment: Yes and use the hashbang method. If this is not what you want you need to do something on your webserver to make sure it not returning 404s or something else